# Do I have to write "BufferedReader ..." in every method?

Tags: java

I am learning java programming. Do I have to write `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` again and again in every method in which I have to take input from user? If some other alternatives exist, kindly suggest them.

Comment: "Extract method" is a killer feature for you to discover.

Comment: if you write the same code again and again -> refactor it to a separate method.

Comment: Yeah, frankly it's kinda dumb that Java doesn't provide some sort of "factory" for generating file pipes.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should think more carefully at the design of your application.

Usually separating the interaction with the user and the logic of your application is a very good idea.

Ideally you will have a class encapsulating both a `BufferedReader` and something to print to the console and providing methods to get the input you need and to show the user the information he should be aware of.

In order to have this work you will have to create a new instance of that class and pass it to all the classes that need to interact with the user.

In this way you clearly separate the distinct concerns of your application and this separation will improve the maintainability of your application. Think for instance what would happen if you are required to write a graphical user interface in addition to the textual user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, there are two possible answers:

If you are using the output stream for debugging, do whatever you like (as long as it works for you), it's your code.  Other user's answers are suitable for this.

If, however, you are using it for the actual program, you should do one of the following:

- Pass the output stream as a parameter to each method that will use it, or
- Have each method return a string that the main program will output.

For major input/output methods, like a 'prompt user for input until they input a valid value', you should pass the stream as a parameter, like so:

**Incorrect:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    promptUserForInput();
}
public static int promptUserForInput(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.console().reader());
    PrintWriter out = System.console().writer();
    out.print("Enter an integer:");
    // [...]
}
```

**Correct:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    promptUserForInput(System.console());
}
public static int promptUserForInput(Console io){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(io.reader());
    PrintWriter out = io.writer();
    out.print("Enter an integer:");
    // [...]
}
```

The other case, where the method does not need live interaction with the user, it should return a `String` object that the interaction methods will use.

**Incorrect:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    printMsg("bob", "tuna fish", "pickles", "rye");
}
public static String printMsg(String person, String type, String topping, String bread){
    System.out.printf("%1$s wants a %2$s sandwich with %3$s on %4$s bread%n",
            person, type, topping, bread);
}
```

**Correct:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(generateMsg("bob", "tuna fish", "pickles", "rye"));
}
public static String generateMsg(String person, String type, String topping, String bread){
    return String.format("%1$s wants a %2$s sandwich with %3$s on %4$s bread",
            person, type, topping, bread);
}
```

There is one other improvement, and this I think reaches more to the point of your question.  You can create a factory class to instantiate your readers and writers for you:

```
public class InputFactory {
    public static InputStreamReader inStreamReader(InputStream in){
        return new InputStreamReader(in);
    }
    public static BufferedReader bufferedReader(InputStream in){
        return new BufferedReader(inStreamReader(in));
    }
    public static Scanner scanner(InputStream in){
        return new Scanner(inStreamReader(in));
    }
}
```

You can add as many overloads to that as you like, so you can call just one function to construct the desired input stream type from any input stream, or even other potential input sources, like files.  To get a `BufferedReader` from an `InputStream`, call `InputFactory.bufferedReader(myInputStream)`.  While that still is a little long, the auto-completion features in eclipse can help enter it quickly, which it won't do as well if you just use the chained constructors.

Comment: @MarcoForberg Thanks, fixed it.  One other error I corrected: The methods also needed to be static, because they are called from a static context

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a `static` variable:

```
public static BufferedReader br = 
                       new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and access it from each relevant method accordingly.

Also, take a look at [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), a utility class that makes reading input from the user easier.

---

As @mariosangiorgio points out, it is important to take into consideration what parts of your program are doing what. You should generally split up your code into logically consistent chunks, and this means separating code that deals with I/O from code that deals with core logic. Consequently, when designing any serious application, the `static`-variable approach might not be the best one as it could undermine this philosophy of "code separation" in certain contexts. Nevertheless, for someone who is just learning, it should pose no problem.

Comment: Using a `static` variable is not a very good idea as it introduces an high coupling between the different components of your system.

Comment: @mariosangiorgio While I would agree with you in general, I don't think that statement is universally true, and does have some degree of dependance on the context of the OP's program.

Comment: I guess that the OP does not have too much experience and probably the program he has to write is not too complex. However I think that it is better to highlight the possible problems with this approach so that he can think at alternative solutions, which of course are more elaborate but that can lead to more maintainable and better structured programs

Answer (score 0):

It depends, you can pass it as a argument to your methods or make it class atribute like

```
public class Something {
     private BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReaddoinger(System.in));
}
```

or even make it public static variable in order to access it from other classes

```
public static BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReaddoinger(System.in));
```

Comment: Why would you ever make it a class attribute?

Comment: If it is a class attribute you can easily create different classes to address the different concerns of your application. I.e. a class to manage the logic and another addressing only the interaction with the user.

Comment: Look into Dependency Injection.  Create a class that handles input (encapsulating the BufferedReader stuff) and inject that class into your controller.  Later you can inject a different class that, say, reads the data from a database instead.  Loose coupling like that means your application and business logic wouldn't need to change if you changed the way you input data.